# Natural Language Processing for data extraction from PDF

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have many different formats of scanned pdfs with many different fields. Think of it as an invoice that has been scanned. I need to extract the information from the scanned pdf and output the fields and the texts that are in each of the fields.

I have an OCR tool that does a good job in extracting all the texts in the raw format. I somehow using NLP have to be able to extract the fields and their values from the raw text. As there are many formats of the invoice, using OCR is not an option in this case. How could NLP help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most NLP tools are designed to extract data from statements. If you don't have punctuation, it might not work out well. If you are using an NLU service, like https://mynlu.com you also will need to provide examples of common phrases and the locations of the relevant data contained therein (entities). If you can split this into statements, something like myNLU or another NLU service (LUIS, Watson etc) can get you out the door in < 10 minutes.